# Document.ready with/without function, and adding an array to existing code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I think this is a really newbie question so thank you for helping me learn. I'm trying to implement a client side Google Analytics experiment am following the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side).

I have always used document.ready like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

and the instructions here recommend this (without *function*):

```
$(document).ready(
  // Execute the chosen view
  pageVariations[chosenVariation]
);
```

I have a few other functions I want to call on the same page outside of the experiment but when I try to combine them into one document.ready, the google analytics experiment will not run.  So I have two questions:

1. When is it OK not to include *function* with document.ready? Looking at the documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), I don't ever see it written without function so not I'm not clear on this
2. What is the correct way to add `pageVariations[chosenVariation]` to my existing document.ready?  I have tried adding it to my code as shown below but the experiment only works if it is inside its own, separate document.ready.

   ```
           <script>
               var chosenVariation = cxApi.chooseVariation();
               var pageVariations = [
                 function() {
                   console.log('variation one');
                 }, 
                 function() { 
                   document.getElementById('hero').src = 'heroB.jpg';
                   document.getElementById('oval').src = 'es_03b.jpg';
                   console.log('variation two');

                 }
               ];
               $(document).ready(function () { 
                   pageVariations[chosenVariation];
                   about();
                   truck();
                   $("#vid").click(function() {    
                       $.fancybox({
                           autoSize: false,
                           inline:true, 
                           height: 456,
                           width: 700,
                           href:"#cab"
                           });
                       }); 
               });         
           </script>
   ```

Comment: As long as `pageVariations[chosenVariation]` is referencing a **function** it is absolutely fine. The first parameter of document.ready **is** a function, but you can either declare it somewhere else, reference it through an array or just use an anonymous function (like the regular "function(){ }" you see).

Comment: I'll also add that it is perfectly acceptable to have more than one `$(document).ready.....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When is it OK not to include function with document.ready? Looking at
>   the documentation here, I don't ever see it written without function
>   so not I'm not clear on this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Something here
});
```

and

```
var a = function() {
   // Something here
};
$(document).ready(a);
```

or

```
$(function(){
   // something here
});
```

Are the exact same thing.

In a nutshell, **as long as the first parameter is a function (either referenced or not) it is absolutely fine to load it through external variables**.

To clarify: in the first case (and the third one) you use an **anonymous function**, while in the seconde case you **reference** a function through a variable.

What you are doing in your situation through:

```
// Wait for the DOM to load, then execute the view for the chosen variation.
$(document).ready(
  // Execute the chosen view
  pageVariations[chosenVariation]
);
```

is basically the same as the second point (the one with the variable a) but, instead of referencing it through a variable, you are referencing it through an array.

Next, about your seconds point, since you are inside a function and you are not referencing it, you should **execute** that function in order to make it work, so, instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    pageVariations[chosenVariation];
            about();
            truck();
            $("#vid").click(function() {    
                $.fancybox({
                    autoSize: false,
                    inline:true, 
                    height: 456,
                    width: 700,
                    href:"#cab"
                    });
                }); 
});
```

Replace:

```
pageVariations[chosenVariation];
```

With:

```
pageVariations[chosenVariation]();
```

EDIT:

As pointed out by Ted above, it is also perfectly fine to have multiple document ready calls so, if you are having trouble with it, you can also do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(
  // Execute the chosen view
  pageVariations[chosenVariation]
);

$(document).ready(function(){
   // The rest of your code here
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a great explanation and now this all makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The properties of the `pageVariations` object are functions. Therefore in the first example, it works because you pass the reference to the function to be executed on `document.ready`. In your second case, where you are using an anonymous function, you again use the reference of the function, but do not assign it to a variable nor execute the function. To do the latter, you need to follow the call with brackets - `()`. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    pageVariations[chosenVariation]();
    // rest of your code...
});
```